# Is there a way to upload data from FTP server to Amazon S3?

Tags: powershell, file-upload, amazon-s3, ftp

Currently, we are transferring around 15 midsize csv files from a FTP server to another storage location and uploading the files to amazon S3 from there. We use windows servers. Is there a way to upload the files directly from FTP to S3? Has anyone used powershell script to do this?

Many thanks!

Comment: You could Do FTP to another server then upload to s3.... all with powershell.

Comment: Thank you for your replies. We currently do have a server in the middle where we download the files, but that has become a maintenance issue for us. BenH, thank you for pointing out the link, I believe this is what I was looking for.